# If the processor is always spinning, why does it drain more resources sometimes and not others?

Tags: sleep, thread-sleep

I've had a massive curiosity as to this for a long time. How do processors "sleep"? As far as I can tell it spins until a set time, that's fine. But there's a problem with this, if the processor is always running at full speed, then why does it get noisy and heat up when it's from my program but stay quiet and not drain power during the OS idle spinning?

Does this have more to do with shared variable access? Even a spin lock requires checking a register with a shared variable. So would it require an external device I/O to actually heat up, or is there a "different sleep"?

I've always wondered how to put my program into a sleep() and know it won't drain battery, (admittedly before I learned about OS schedules/time slicing).

In short, how does this work, and how would I ensure that my Sleep() or otherwise spin-locks use the low-power type.

Comment: the processor is *not* always spinning, at least not in the same rate. also, on some hardware, unutilized circuity can be powered down

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT

Comment: Those comments help, it looks like I can only yield to IRQ's and do busy-waiting for network requests and similar... Might seek an example in C, as I'm only familiar with iOS sdk